# laravel-php tag displayed as string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new at laravel framework and I am trying to create CRUD. The problem is that tags used at view are displayed as a string . I am following [this](http://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers) tutorial.

```
<body>
<div class="container">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse"> 
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="{{ URL::to('customers') }}">View All Customers</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ URL::to('nerds/create') }}">Create a Customer</a>
    </ul>
</nav>

<h1>Create a Customer</h1>

<!-- if there are creation errors, they will show here -->
{{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'nerds')) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
        {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
        {{ Form::email('email', Input::old('email'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    {{ Form::submit('Create the Customer!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}

</div>
</body>
```

And it displays:

```
{{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }} {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'nerds')) }}
{{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }} {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
{{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }} {{ Form::email('email', Input::old('email'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
{{ Form::submit('Create the Customer!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }} {{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Can we see your PHP code that builds this view?  Does the file have this extension: `.blade.php`?

Comment: public function index()
 {
  
  $customers = Customers::all();

  
  return View::make('customers.index')
   ->with('customers', $customers);
 }

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the view file extension is `.blade.php` and not just `.php`

Comment: it is .blade.php and still displays it as string. What may be the problem?

Comment: Ok try this: Change all of your blade form tag calls from `{{ Form:: }}` to `{{{ Form:: }}}` (ie. use three curly braces instead of two). The reason for this is that in L4 they have swapped the default behaviour of `{{` and `{{{`, so now `{{` escapes by default and `{{{` does not. Read about it [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/206). Let me know if this works, if it does I'll edit my answer and add this info to it with a better explanation :)

Comment: no even that way doesn't work. and variable is .blade.php. I dont understand why doesn't works